# emacs daemon and magit

Tags: git, emacs, daemon, magit

I've been trying out emacs as a server, and have run into a problem with magit. We have a Gitlab server at work, and when I try to use magit for a push or a pull, I'm challenged for a password. This doesn't happen when I use git from the command line, and, more importantly, it doesn't happen if I run emacs "directly" (as opposed to running emacsclient with the daemon).
I should mention that I'm running on Ubuntu 15.04, and I'm using emacs 25.

I'm wondering if other people have run into this behavior? Or can point me to a remedy? Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestions in the existing answers led me to finding a solution. I'm hoping that it will be helpful to others who run into this problem. I'm using systemd to launch the emacs daemon, and it turned out that I needed an additional directive in the emacsd.service file:

```
[Service]
...
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
...
```

So, thanks for the leads - they put me on the right track to find the answer.

Comment: Noce catch, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the protocol used for the upstream repo url.

Typically, a password is asked when ssh doesn't find the proper private/public key in `$HOME/.ssh`.
And `$HOME` can differ when a service is launched as a daemon, as opposed to launched by a user.

So if the upstream GitLab repo is accessed by an ssh url, that would explain the difference between the two attempts.

Comment: The possible difference in values for $HOME is suggestive. It's funny, though, that other things that I'd expect to be affected (like the contents of my .emacs.d directory) seem to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first to have issues with this to say the least. Which is why it is mentioned in the FAQ, which takes you to [Pushing with Magit from Windows](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows).

That summarizes the various options and contains troubleshooting instructions. But still not everyone was able to figure it out (or provide accurate enough information for us to diagnose from a distance), so a core contributor wrote a package which makes this work even on insufficiently configured systems. That package is also mentioned on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not sure it's relevant to my situation. I'm running on LInux, and emacs/magit work fine when I'm not connecting to an emacs server.